# Bug with Badges?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, statistics

The first bug I noticed was that I have a question [Java (1.6.0_15) not working on Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6.2). Why?](https://superuser.com/questions/78089/java-1-6-0-15-not-working-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-10-6-2-why) that has been viewed over 1000 times yet I never got the Popular Question badge? If you [check here](https://superuser.com/badges/26/popular-question?userid=14390) you can see what I mean.

The second bug would be that "I think" I should have the Electorate badge by now with over 980+ up votes? Again I said "I think" because I have no way of checking the statistics. I have checked other users too that have upvotes in the 1000+ range and they also have not got this badge so I am wondering if there is a bug or the 25% on questions has not yet been achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No bug; you have a deleted question for which you probably already earned that second badge "early".

[image]

The count is correct. Two *non-deleted* questions with 1k views, two Popular Question badges.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on that.

Comment: However if you look here the Java related question is not present: http://superuser.com/badges/26/popular-question?userid=14390

Comment: @ricbax the badge count is synced, so 2=2 (you need two, you already have two) and it won't award again. One of those was awarded on the now-deleted question.

Comment: I understand what you are saying Jeff, but by following the link provided and seeing the 2 actual awarded badges, shouldn't it be the 2 non-deleted questions? At the moment it shows the 1 non-deleted and the 1 deleted.

Answer (score 3):

The badges are run as part of a batch process, so give it some time, perhaps it will pick it up.

Electorate [requires that](https://superuser.com/badges/49/electorate) you vote on 600+ questions **and** 25% of total votes are on questions.

> Voted on **600 questions and** 25% or more of total votes are **on questions**.

Are you sure your votes meet that criteria ?

Comment: Is there a viewable schedule of when batches are run? Like I said "I think" according to my written stats (yes I keep track on paper) I should be there or pretty darn close. I did another look of other profiles that have it and some superusers have 2000+ and just received it. I usually vote more for questions than answers which should cover the 25%. As for the first bug I will monitor for the remainder of the month and revisit this question if no change.

Comment: `Is there a viewable schedule of when batches are run` - Not to my knowledge.  `I did another look of other profiles that have it and some superusers have 2000+ and just received it.` - trivia - I received my electorate badge around ~ 1800 votes range - but then again, that's my voting pattern of having voted on more answers than questions ( since I'm pretty liberal with voting on answers, esp. since a question is more likely to have multiple answers)

Answer (score 3):

Some badges do take some time to appear due to the batch processing of some badges.  I believe the "Electorate" badge is one of those.  Mine took a long time to show up also, so it should show up eventually as long as you met the 25% requirement.

In responce to the "Popular Question" badge, looking at your profile.  You have 2x of the "Popular Quesition" badges and you have 2 questions with over 1000 views. There is a old question of yours that is deleted also that had over 1000 views.  I have not seen a case of badges being reversed, but it may explain why it is not awarding any new ones.

Comment: There are 3 questions with 1k+ views, one of them ( http://superuser.com/questions/66209/iphone-application-that-monitors-daily-weekly-monthly-bandwidth-closed ) is deleted